# Mongo DB GridFS + Document transaction (typical use-case)

Tags: .net, mongodb, database

I've become from MSSQL world to mongo and I've got the unaswered question about typical use-case. (I don't found information about it on official site).
I thing U all did something like this:

For example:
I want to safe some file + metadata (filename + file length).

1. **"Create document object"**: var document = new MyDocument("file1.txt", 65536);
2. **"Save stream"**: var streamId = GridFS.Upload(myStream);
3. **"Link stream with metadata"**: document.StreamId =  streamId;
4. **"Save document"**: myDocumentCollection.Insert(document);

**Questions**:

1) Because there is no transactions how I should handle situation if my operation would fail after step **2** - there would be only stream itself. What the right way to handle it? Database sharding into 10 servers and pray that it will never fail? Create background services to clean inconsistent records?

2) How to handle GridFS properly: delete document+stream, rewrite stream in fail tolerance manner?

3) How to handle situations when my operation needs to change a couple of objects?

Answer (score 0):

1 & 2) You should get a MongoGridFSException when the upload fails. So just handle it in the catch clause in the matter you see fit. If the metadata is not too large, you can also use the alternative [upload api](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/current/html/64fa95c4-9501-f663-e8d4-dbe729a9f246.htm) and pass the metadata through the createOptions parameter.

3) For more general cases, if you want to make sure that the last operation succeeded, you can use the [getLastError command](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/getLastError+Command) to make sure that there was no error with the last operation.